# Job-level throttling and priority-setting in bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Google cloud bigtable deployment with several tables and several jobs reading/writing from it. Once in a while, someone starts a job that eats up most of the bigtable bandwidth and other jobs are not able to access bigtable.

Is there a way I can specify per-job qps limits or priorities so that one job doesn't use all the bandwidth or cpu?

Comment: This is currently not possible as there are no per-job settings, but that's an interesting use case and feature, so thank you for the feedback! Happy to chat with you about your use case and requirements further, if you'd like. I'm the PM for Cloud Bigtable; feel free to reach out via LinkedIn.

Comment: Some users increase the number of Cloud Bigtable nodes before a job, and constrain the number of client side processors.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Bigtable does not support per-job QPS limits. However we do now have support for [Replication](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/replication-overview) which can help with separating and isolating workloads into different clusters to avoid having batch queries affect live serving traffic, for example. You can create a setup with multiple clusters of different sizes, and use [application profiles](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/app-profiles) to direct how individual groups of queries are routed.

You can configure your different jobs to use different application profiles with different routing policies.

For rate throttling and other sophisticated job and client management I'd recommend looking into [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) which can help you apply these kinds of policies to your workloads.